# Secure Rails 5 API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have created a Rails 5 API application. I have set methods to return JSON for GET requests.

The data is to be maintained only by me and thus I want the app to return 401 for all type of data create or update requests. **How can I achieve this?**

Also if I comment out the def create, def update functions in controller file, how will I update & create data using POST requests?

> **AIM:-**
>
> Set up a secure API which accepts GET requests only from my domain and return 401 otherwise.
>
> And accept POST, UPDATE and DELETE requests manually after authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set up a token authentication for your API. To quickly set up one you can install this gem:

[devise-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/README.md)

Just follow the instructions to set up your authentication system. This way you'll be able to control who is authenticated to make request to your API.

This gem is awesome because after installing you only need to make some really minor tweaks to get it working, and therefore, securing your API.

You'll probably end up doing something like this in your controller(s)

```
before_action: authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :update, ... Any other method you want to protect]`
```

**EDIT: Elaborating**

Basically you want to protect one or more of your resources. You'll also want to make your API stateless, so it won't save any session data.

Once you install the gem you should run:

```
rails g devise_token_auth:install User auth
```

This will create a user model, adjust your routes.rb to mount a authentication module and create a migration.

Then you'll have to `rails db:migrate`

As I said there are many ways of protecting your resources, but one of the most common ways is to run authenticate_user! On a before_action in your controller(s):

`before_action: authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :update, ... Any other method you want to protect]`

Basically, from now on every request a user make to your protected methods will need to be authenticated.

I suggest you read a bit more on authentication and API's. But, basically from now on, to make a request to your API, the request's headers will have to contain a UID, client, and a token. **If they do not include those, a 401 status will be returned as a response.** Therefore, protecting your API from unauthenticated requests.

Some useful tutorials:

1) [link](http://www.developingandrails.com/2015/02/api-authentication-with-devisetokenauth.html?m=1) 
2) [link2](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/authentication-with-angularjs-and-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to set it up for my app _[List of Products]_? The documentation basically talks about users. I'm new to Rails and don't know much about it.

Comment: Updated response with more elaborated solutions and some useful tutorials links that I know will be extremely helpful for you :D

Comment: @Shivam hope you find it useful. :D

Comment: No problem! If you found my answer helpful to solve your problem, please mark as accepted answer :)

Comment: That was really helpful :) Can you please answer this too: Receiving GET requests from my domain only & returning 401 otherwise?

Comment: I believe you must open a new question. Just post the link and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Made a quick edit to answer your question. :D

Comment: Thanks but I want my GET requests not to require authentication yet have some sort of request origin security. Created question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185925/check-origin-in-rails-5-api

Comment: Thanks for all the help :) 
I have set up the authentication on my app but using the credentials in my frontend JS exposes it to everyone.